# How can I find an $f'(x)$ such that $f'(x) = f(x)(1 - f(x))$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

One function I use often is the logistic sigmoid function:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

Its derivative has the property such that:

$$\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \\
&= \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2} \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\right) \\
&= f(x)(1 - f(x))
\end{align}$$

But this is a function and derivative that I know by heart. How could I find an $f'(x)$ that satisfies the condition $f'(x) = f(x)(1 - f(x))$ without using an existing example? Do other functions exist?

This appears as a question on a unit in integration, so I've tagged it as such. I know one such example but not how to algebraically come to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=f(x)(1 - f(x))$$
$$\implies \frac{df(x)}{f(x)-f^2(x)}=dx$$
$$\implies \ln\left|f(x)\right|-\ln\left|1-f(x)\right|=x+C$$
$$\implies \ln\left|\frac{f(x)}{1-f(x)}\right|=x+C$$
$$\implies \frac{f(x)}{1-f(x)}=Ce^x$$
$$\implies f(x)=Ce^x-Ce^xf(x)$$
$$\implies f(x)=\frac{Ce^x}{1+Ce^x}$$

Answer (score 2):

Separation of variables. $f' = df/dx=f(1-f)$, so $ dx = 1/(f(1-f)df$. Now integrate both sides of the equality (do not forget an additive constant).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ is never $0$ or $1$. Then by dividing the LHS by $f(x)(1-f(x))$, we get

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} + \frac{f'(x)}{1 - f(x)} = 1$$ Integrating from $0$ to $t$ (and then replacing t by x), we get the general form $\frac{f(x)}{1 - f(x)} = e^x/c$, which gets us $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + ce^{-x}}$.

If $f$ is $0$ or $1$ you can prove that it is a constant function.